# Using Django, how can I avoid the duplicity of code when showing the details of a row inside a bootstrap modal?

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

I have a table where I show some item fields. When the user clics a button it opens a modal with all the item information. I'm using a "for loop" to get the rows but I noticed that it also creates a modal for each row.

This is the line that includes the modal template:
`{% include 'item_detail.html' with pin=item.pin %}`

If I place the modal out of the "for loop" it loses context and doesn't show the item information.

This is my for loop:

```
 <tbody class="items-table-body">
  {% for item in items %}

  <tr scope="row">
    <td>{{item.client_name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
    <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
    <td>{{item.creation_date}}</td>
    <td>{{item.get_status_display}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" 
                class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
                name="button" 
                data-toggle="modal" 
                data-target="#itemDetailModal">

          <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
        </button>

        {% include 'item_detail.html' with pin=item.pin %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% empty %}
  <p>No items created</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This is a short version of my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" 
     id="itemDetailModal" 
     tabindex="-1" 
     role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="itemDetailModalTitle" 
     aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" 
         role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               ...
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some JS in order to achieve what you want. Here are some tips on how to proceed:

1. Create a JS function that displays a modal.
2. Parametrize such function with the values you want to use in the modal.
3. Create an HTML template for the modal (in order to replace the values received in the function).
4. bind the function to some button/link and pass the parameters.
5. Your modal (JS) must call a Django view in order to perform its work.

Example **(Be aware, sudo-code used here)**:

```
// modal.js
modal_template = // template here. 

function display_modal(title, amount, ...) {
    modal = populate_template(title, amount, ...);
    modal.show();
}
```

In templates:

```
{# template.html #}
{% for item in items %}
    ...
   <button onclick="display_modal({{ item.title }}, {{ title.amount }}, ...") />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I understand your steps but I get lost with your example (sorry, I'm learning with this project). Do you have any questions about my code so your example could fit my problem better?

Comment: I've edited the answer in order to match a little more your code. I hope it helps, if you hace any question , please ask.